# Django user with extra fields- extending User

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

Hey I'm new to allauth package.
I would like to know how to write a user model that extends the all auth user.
for example i would like to have a user that has allauth user fields in it and also an image, list of favorite text field.

I would realy appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the Django user model using an `OneToOneField(User)`. 
Here's the relevant part of the Django docs: [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

IF you need it you can use a custom user model but this will be more difficult. In this case see [allauth custom user models](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models) and [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Thank you! it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want allauth user fields with some extra fields, you can inherit default user model and add your custom fields to it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ExtendedUser(AbstractUser):
  favourites = models.charField(max_length=255)
  ....
  ....
```

In your settings.py file, add this line

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.ExtendedUser'
```

To store the extra fields when user signs up, use django-allauth signals as in your views as follows.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def user_signed_up(request, user, **kwargs)
  #get extra fields from kwargs and save to database
```